# UWP app to access only specific folder on user's machine

Tags: c#, uwp

Declaring an [App Capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) in manifest file, we can have our `UWP` app access certain folders such as Pictures, Videos, Music etc.

Moreover, the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability allows apps to get the same access to the file system as the user who is currently running the app without any additional file-picker style prompts during runtime.

But how about even if the user has access to his/her entire system but wants a `UWP` app to access only a specific folder needed for the app to have `read access`. Can we implement such a functionality in a UWP app without using file-picker?

**Why do I need that**?: Our app reads files from a folder that is too big to be included inside the app and has tons of files of various types inside it. Only read-access is needed.

Comment: declare `broadFileSystemAccess` and then read just the folder you need. Is there a problem with this? (disclaimer: I have minimal knowledge of UWP)

Comment: @bolov Second paragraph and the first sentence of the third paragraph of the post may answer your inquiry.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't get it. The way I understand your context: the user has access to the entire system, so it has access to the the specific folder. The `broadFileSystemAccess` gives UWP app the same access like the user. Since the user has access to the folder, the UWP app with `broadFileSystemAccess` will have access to the specific folder. So use `broadFileSystemAccess` and access the folder for reading inside the app. Again, could very well be my ignorance of how UWP works.

Comment: @bolov Most users would have access to the entire system (e.g. user's own laptop) but new `UWPs` have new functionality of being sandboxed meaning app cannot access any system resources, data, etc. other than what is inside app's sandbox. There are some exceptions such as the ones defined [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). And one of those exceptions is the declaration of `broadFileSystemAccess` but - as the name implies - that declaration should only be used under very special circumstances. So, we don't want to use `broadFileSystemAccess`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation

Comment: Thinking outside of the box a little here. Make your app on first use download the folder to its own app data location. That way the app remains small, no special permissions required and the assets needed are downloaded on first use, or when first needed. No user intervention required, other than maybe an accept to download big data. I suggest this because from your post it seems that the folder needed is provided by you and the user has to download it separately in your current scenario.

Comment: @bolov Yes, the folder is provided for download. But, I'm not sure if a UWP app can have an entire folder (specially a large data folder) downloaded inside it have it's code read it. But I'll investigate.

Answer (score 0):

> But how about even if the user has access to his/her entire system but wants a UWP app to access only a specific folder needed for the app to have read access.

You could not create that folder only has read access capability for current user. And the folder's attribute is control on the system level. You could only create the folder and set attribute as read only for other user. And that could not be achieved([`System.IO.File.SetAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setattributes?view=netframework-4.8)) in uwp platform.

> Yes, the folder is provided for download. But, I'm not sure if a UWP app can have an entire folder (specially a large data folder) downloaded inside it have it's code read it.

For the requirement, you could store the download in your app's [`LocalFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/br241621) and  there are no general size restriction on local data stored. And it only could be accessed for current app.

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

Certainly, you could also store the large data in the [`Download`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.downloadsfolder) folder. For more info please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data).

Comment: How can we have user copy the downloaded folder into `LocalFolder`? Suppose user downloaded the folder, say, `SomeFolder`  that the UWP app requires to read. Now I want the user to copy that folder to the `LocalFolder`. How can that happen - can you explain or give an example?

Comment: If you want to copy file to local folder please refer [`StorageFile.CopyAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.copyasync) method.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to provide you the logic of why your request is conflicting and thus not implemented at the system level.

Sandboxing means that the app has the access only to its own folders. From the system aspect the only exception to that rule could be that some folders are not considered security critical (like Pictures, Music, Downloads) and you may declare access to those folders. The second exception is if the user gives you access to the folder. In both of those cases sandboxing is not broken because the expansion of the sandbox is not arbitrary. As soon as you arbitrarily want to expand the sandbox, there is no difference in safety between having access to whole the system and few folders that you randomly pick. I am not sure how do you see the difference in that - in both case you arbitrarily pick to access some folders just if you have the access to whole the disk you do that from the code while if there was some capability to do that through some declaration then you would do it through declaration. But effects are the same - your app has arbitrary access to the unsafe portions of the disk that depends only on your preferences.